# Points are resetting

Tags: python, count, points

I tried to program a rock paper scissors game in which I will count points, but in every answer the points are resetting back to zero. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code

```
import random

points=0
oppoints=0
opt=["rock","papper","scissors"]
ans="yes"

def result(name,win,loose,points,oppoints):
    if cho==name:
        if opp==win:
            points += 1
            print("congrats you got a point")
        elif opp==loose:
            oppoints += 1
            print("you lost the point")
        else :
            print("its a tie no one gets a point")
            print("points" ,points)
            print("oppoints" ,oppoints)

while ans == "yes" :

    while points < 2 or oppoints < 2 :

        cho=input("rock papper scissors: ")
        opp=random.choice(opt)
        print("opponent: " +opp)
        result("rock","scissors","papper",points,oppoints)
        result("papper","rock","scissors",points,oppoints)
        result("scissors","papper","rock",points,oppoints)
    
    if points>oppoints :
        print("you win!!")
    else:
        print("you lost :(")

    ans=input("wanna play again?? ")

    if ans == "yes":
        points=0
        oppoints=0

print("good bye")
```

Comment: `points += 1` and `oppoints += 1` don't change the variables outside the `result` function, it creates new numbers and binds those to the variables only inside the `result` function.

Comment: at the end of the return function: `return points, oppoints` in the same indentation as `if cho==name` and then you can call the function with `points, oppoints = result("rock","scissors","papper",points,oppoints)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `points` variable in your `results` function is seen as a new local variable and only changed in the scope of the function. It's the typical "pass by reference vs value" issue.
If you want to change the value outside of the function, you can, e.g. return the new points.

```
def result(name,win,loose,points,oppoints):
if cho==name:
    if opp==win:
        points += 1
        print("congrats you got a point")
    elif opp==loose:
        oppoints += 1
        print("you lost the point")
    else :
        print("its a tie no one gets a point")
        print("points" ,points)
        print("oppoints" ,oppoints)
 return points, oppoints
```

and then call with:

```
points, oppoints = result("rock","scissors","papper",points,oppoints)
```